# M syntax, trying to create a table in Power query

Tags: powerbi, powerquery, powerbi-desktop

I am trying to create a table in Power query but I keep getting a weird error (can't apply field access to type number) for the fields I am trying to summarize (the rest of fields are ok).

```
let Source = #"Portfolio Reporting",
#"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(Source, {"Project", "Expense Type", "Date"}, {{"Actuals", each List.Sum(List.Select([Value], each [Versions] = "Actuals")), type nullable number}, {"Current Budget", each List.Sum(List.Select([Value], each [Versions] = "Current Budget")), type nullable number}, {"Current Forecast", each List.Sum(List.Select([Value], each [Versions] = "Current Fcst")), type nullable number}})
in
#"Grouped Rows"
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: What is your underlying data? This is not enough to go on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this in powerquery,

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Date", type date}}),
#"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Changed Type", {"Project", "Expense Type", "Date"}, {
    {"Actuals", each List.Sum(Table.SelectRows(_, each [Versions] = "Actuals")[Value])},
    {"Current Budget", each List.Sum(Table.SelectRows(_, each [Versions] = "Current Budget")[Value])},
    {"Current Forecast", each List.Sum(Table.SelectRows(_, each [Versions] = "Current Fcst")[Value])}
    })
in #"Grouped Rows"
```

which is basically the same as pivoting:

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Date", type date}}),
#"Pivoted Column" = Table.Pivot(#"Changed Type", List.Distinct(#"Changed Type"[Versions]), "Versions", "Value", List.Sum)
in  #"Pivoted Column"
```

[image]